# AppFabric installation error 1603 (As_Observers)

Tags: windows, appfabric, windows-server-2012

Hi I have been trying to install AppFabric for hours! After trying to do it on an existing Server I got to the point to use a fresh copy of Windows 2012 Server R2. Still getting errors.
I believe I found the error in the log file:

```
CustomAction Usergroup_AS_Observers_icacls_i returned actual error code 2 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)MSI (s) (B8:F8) [13:10:01:738]: Product: AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server -- Error 1722. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.
```

Deleting the Usergroup as recommended in different posts does not help. The user group gets created during install.

I have no idea how to approach this.

I have tried on an existing AD-integrated Server, new 2012 and 2012R2 image. It is not possible to install.

Answer (score 1):

To fix AppFabric installation issue 1603 I removed PSModulePath from environment variables.

Comment: I saw this fix earlier. It does not help on my machine.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your issue correctly: During executing the AppFabric setup file WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64.exe you are receiving an 1603 issue and in the detailed log file you find the message above with the 1722 issue? Or do you have an issue during Configure AppFabric?

Comment: exactly! Here is a link to the complete log: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=C8A3D88A63505273!11550&authkey=!AOboHzpGo0L3veM&ithint=file%2ctxt

Comment: Wired. I cannot reproduce it. Just to verify we are doing the same thing here: You are trying to install [this](http://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=27115) binary on Windows 2012 and 2012R2? During the setup you are retrieving a popup with exactly this error message: "Appfabric installation failed because installer MSI returned with error code:1603"? Can you check how PSModulePath looks like by typing in this command on a PowerShell console: `Get-Content env:PSModulePath`?

Comment: yes, exactly! PSModulePath returns: C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\